# Add pageview event to google tag manager + gatsby

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I am tryting to add custom data layer snippet (dataLayer.push(❴’event’: “pageview”❵)) to Gatbsy GTM plugin. How do I do it? Anybod help?

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({ originalLocation: document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.hostname + document.location.pathname + document.location.search });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook in your component/page. A `useEffect` is an event that is triggered once the DOM tree is loaded (similar to `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` lifecycles combined).

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined'){
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      window.dataLayer.push({ originalLocation: document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.hostname + document.location.pathname + document.location.search });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Your page</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note the `typeof window !== 'undefined'` condition, a recommended statement when [dealing with global objects (such as `window` or `document`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/)) in server-side rendering.

Comment: is there any difference with gatsby-route-change or should I use these together?

Comment: It's better to use the native approach in https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager/ . However, if you need to add a custom `dataLayer` property in some events, it's much more easy to use the `useEffect`.